# Python Selenium unable to click 'Save' button in form

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver to check a box in a form and click save on the same page. The checkbox works fine, but cannot click save. I have tried multiple solutions without a working solution. I add a sleep as after clicking save manually it does take a while to process.

Here is the html for the save button:

```
<input class="cbi-button cbi-button-apply" type="submit" name="cbi.apply" value="Save">
```

Here is my code using xpath (attempt 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']").click()
time.sleep(20)
```

Output from attempt 1:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Attempt 2 using action chains as suggested by another answer:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name(u"cbi-page-actions")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
time.sleep(20)
```

There are no errors raised in this second attempt but from watching the browser the save button did not seem to be clicked. I have also checked afterwards on the page and the  changes I added were definitely not saved.

I've also attempted using webforms however I have the opposite problem where I am able to save the form but cannot select the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait before, may be the element was not loaded properly, not after triggering the `click`

**Solution 1: Direct click with worst type of Explicit wait**

```
time.sleep(20)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']").click()
```

**Solution 2: Using Actions chain :**

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Save']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

**Solution 3: Using dynamic Explicit wait:-**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "cbi.apply"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Solution 4: Using Js**

```
button = driver.find_element_by_name("cbi.apply")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```